# drupal white screen of death on modules and stucture

Tags: drupal, module, crash

I have a drupal site configured and running in my local host which working perfectly.

But when it's uploaded to a remote host I get a whitescreen of death when trying to access modules and structure in the admin menu.

Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the reports, which might be able to identify whether a setting on the server is not correct, or perhaps permissions. IT would also help to know what Drupal version you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time i've learned about this

```
function shutdown(){
  var_dump(error_get_last());
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
```

it always shows the last error before the process ends

Answer (score 3):

Enable error logging by putting this in your `settings.php`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

This might give you some better error information to work from.

**EDIT:** As noted by Clive in the comments, you should add this to the top of `index.php` so that these error reporting options will be used for any errors that take place even before `settings.php` is loaded.

Comment: It's recommended to put these lines in `index.php`, not `settings.php`, so you can catch errors before `settings.php` has been loaded. See http://drupal.org/node/158043

Comment: thank you it worked, there was a module folder named module_old, and module, duplicated functions, etc.... deleted the _old folder and its working... thank you

Comment: I cannot see any error after ading the above setting in `index.php` at top. I still get White screen without any error in `error log` and `watchdog` log also Can you help me